# MTG dash and undying

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Question about mtg rules.
When my opponent tries to kill [Ragavan](https://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=522214) that I’ve cast for its dash cost and I protect it with [Undying Malice](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=540986).

Does Ragavan go back to my hand or does it stay on the battlefield with a +1/+1 counter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will stay on the battlefield (after it has returned to the battlefield from Undying Malice).

The creature that is on the battlefield after Undying Malice triggers and resolves is not the same one that you cast for the Dash cost. Dash won’t do anything, because this particular Ragavan wasn’t cast for its Dash cost.

> 400.7. An object that moves from one zone to another becomes a new object with no memory of, or relation to, its previous existence. This rule has the following exceptions.

(None of the exceptions are relevant).

Comment: I wonder what percentage of our mtg questions here are answered with 400.7 :)