# MTG - Does Jhoira grant suspend indefinitely?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

When playing [Jhoira of the Ghitu](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Jhoira%20of%20the%20Ghitu) and using her ability, it says if the card doesn’t have suspend, it gains suspend.

Once it’s cast and hits the battlefield, and an opponent exiles it, would I be able to use something like Jhoira’s Timebug to put a time counter on it, since it “gained” the suspend ability back when I activated Jhoira’s ability?  Does that ability remain on the card through zone changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. When the card moves onto the stack and again onto the battlefield, it becomes a new object that does not retain anything from the card that was in exile, including abilities granted to it:

> 400.7. An object that moves from one zone to another becomes a new object with no memory of, or relation to, its previous existence. This rule has the following exceptions.

Some of the exceptions involve the card moving to the stack, but not retaining abilities as it moves to the battlefield.

Note also that even if it did have suspend, Jhoira’s Timebug wouldn’t help, because it only works if the target already has a time counter, and also a card with suspend is not “suspended” unless it has a time counter.

> 702.62b A card is “suspended” if it’s in the exile zone, has suspend, and has a time counter on it.

Comment: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/58957/mtg-dash-and-undying#comment88928_58958 lol

Comment: @PhilipKendall At least this one required me to actually read through all the exceptions listed for 400.7, because it didn't seem unreasonable that one of the exceptions could have been something related to retaining abilities that had been granted to it.